# concatinate text using insert after jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add "per person" after the price on this [page](http://convoy.nyc/buy/minimalist), but it's not working correctly.

so far i have:

```
 window.onload = function per (){
  $( "Per Person" ).insertAfter( ".sqs-money-native" );
  }
```

any idea what i'm missing?

Comment: what is your expected output in HTML

Comment: @JqueryKing "$" [price] + "per person"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".sqs-money-native" ).append( "Per Person" );
});
```

Comment: To add to this answer, if you need it it after that span (the span with the price in it), use  `$( ".product-price" ).append( "Per Person" );` (per code on linked example page)

Comment: thanks for this. just tried it and got an error " Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDocument]' is not a valid selector." any thoughts?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef is it possible to change it to an event listener on load instead of a document?

Comment: @rs202 you can make it as a function  and use it like this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp   or try to remove per .. and try window.onload = function (){.......}

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef thanks for the help. now i have this but it's still not working on the site. but running in the console its fine.

`window.onload = function(){
    $( ".sqs-money-native" ).append( "Per Person" );
}`

Comment: @rs202 make sure you include jquery library .. sometimes simple things make a lot of issues